# How can I pass an exclamation mark to a call-label routine in batch scripts and delayedexpansion is on?

Tags: batch-file, escaping, delayedvariableexpansion

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288552/how-can-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark-in-cmd-scripts), which helps in most cases, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099126/passing-exclamation-marks-as-parameters-in-batch-subroutine-call), which seems a duplicate, but I couldn't get it to work.

Disclaimer: disabling/enabling delayed expansion works as workaround but that's annoying to do, unless the whole script can be disabled. I am curious whether there's a more direct approach.

I use this [brilliantly simple colorEcho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660249/how-do-i-make-one-particular-line-of-a-batch-file-a-different-color-then-the-oth/21666354#21666354) script and sometimes I just want to print an exclamation mark. As that post shows (but fails to address), it doesn't print the exclamation mark.

Repro:

```
@echo Off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize backspace-space-backspace
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)

rem Using it
call :colorEcho 0a "Give me an exclamation!"
echo.
pause
GOTO :EOF

rem The actual color-print hack
:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i
```

Gives:

[image]

I've tried:

- `call :colorEcho 0A "Ex^!"` and variants like `^^^!`
- first `set excl=^^!` then `CALL :colorEcho "Foo!excl!"`
- some variants with more/less escaping
- created a simplified routine without `colorEcho`, but it ran into the same issues:

  ```
  :test
  rem How to call :test with %1 containing an excl mark
  echo %1
  exit /B
  ```

Perhaps this is not possible, and I should either not want to output an exclamation mark, or I should use the already mentioned `DisableDelayedExpansion`. Any ideas?

Comment: Since your script isn't using delayed expansion just remove that line!

Comment: @comp, that's the whole point, I can't.  To keep the question simple, I tried to create a minimal repro example, I need delayed expansion in my main scripts. If I didn't need it, I would use the mentioned workaround, of course ;). I updated the q., for emphasising this, thanks

Comment: You don't need it enabling everywhere though, _as can be seen above_, so keep it disabled until you need it enabling. That could be fairly simple or really difficult, but without seeing your entire script, I couldn't say which of those is true.

Comment: @compo, that's the workaround currently in use if I absolutely need it and it's trivial enough. But I like to be able to pass a param with an exclamation mark. If it's truly not possible, I'll live with it. But I expect there's a way that I'm missing.

Comment: Strangely, my machine showed no newline between the green text and the `pause` output. Side-effect of reductio-ad-minimum?

Comment: @magoo, no, just a copy/paste idiosyncrasy, `colorEcho` doesn't issue a newline by default. Thanks, fixed now.

Comment: @Compo, I just realized that it can be enabled/disabled _per procedure/label_. With that, I can just disable it inside the `:colorEcho` procedure, and it _just works_. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
set "ex=^^^!"
call :colorEcho 0a "Give me an exclamation%%ex%%"
```

But better would be to use call with a variable 9nstead of content.
Because the call command has nasty side effects

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for the trivial case. But in my "main batch file" in `colorEcho`, I assign the variable first to another variable (an update after I posted this), which I think results in double-interpretation of the `%%` (i.e. I have `set TMPFILENAME=%~2`). Can you elaborate on what you mean with "call with variable vs content"?

Comment: While I still do not understand your last "but better" comment, I just realized, prompted by your answer, that if I disable expansion _only for that procedure_, it just works with normal escaping. I.e., add `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion` right below the `:colorEcho` label. Can't believe I didn't think of that previously! Since this command is local to the procedure, only those procedures that require passing in excl marks need to be written without expansion.